# How to get uploaded file name

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I want to access file name from `<input type="file">`
I console `element[0].files` and get this result:

[image]

I want to use image name which highlighted in screenshot.

Comment: @om can you let me know why you not in highlighted "0"?

Comment: @guest271314  it shows `undefined`

Comment: @Njdhv "0" was missed by mistake, I need full image name `0236...03C.jpg`

Comment: `element[0].files[0].name`

Comment: Thanks. it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `FileList` using `.files` property. Get the `File` object at index `0` of `FileList` using bracket notation. Get the `"name"` property of the `File` object using `.name`

```
element[0].files[0].name
```